# How to solve binomial sum but with denominator

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Simple question. How does one give a closed form for this ugly boy? $$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{i}\frac{(1+p)^{k-1-i}(2x-1-p)^{i}}{i}$$

Comment: looks a bit singular at $i=1$ ?

Comment: Oh gosh. That's not good. But it's part of the solution to an integral. Thank you for pointing this out. Time for some expansion!

Comment: I was hoping that you would change $ i -1 \rightarrow i+1$ and start the sum from $i=0$ ... this may give a nicer answer ... maybe tell us about the integral where it came from ? ...

Comment: Can't change it, sadly. It's actually a binomial expansion of ((u+1+p)^(k-1))/u,  where u=2x-1-p. This was done to integrate (x^(k-1))/(2x-1-p) wrt x. This is all in trying to solve what is otherwise quite a simple first order differential equation. I'm quite concerned actually by the singularity - this was arrived at through generating functions for the dynamics of an adaptive network. There shouldn't be any infinity, but I don't know.

Comment: I MADE THE INTEGRAL OF u^(i-1) TO BE (u^i)/(i-1). THAT WAS SO DUMB.

Answer (score 2):

As Donald Splutterwit commented, there is a problem if the summation starts at $i=1$.

However, for 
$$S_k=\sum_{\color{red}{i=2}}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{i}\frac{(1+p)^{k-1-i}(2x-1-p)^{i}}{i-1}$$ let $t=\frac{2 x-p-1}{p+1}$ to get
$$S_k=(p+1)^{k-1}\sum_{{i=2}}^{k-1} \binom{k-1}{i}\frac{t^i }{i-1}$$
which leads to 
$$S_k=\frac{1}{2} (k-2) (k-1) (p+1)^{k-1}\,t^2\,\, _3F_2(1,1,3-k;2,3;-t)$$ where appears an hypergeometric function (which is still a summation).